# Scaling application with RabbitMq and websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, rabbitmq

Lets say that there are 3 instances of application, aplication on one end is accepting web socket connections and on another end it is connected to RabbitMq as an consumer.

Each time when new web socket connection is created, `socket` is saved in JS object and mapped to `customerId` which is available from initial HTTP handshake request when app is about to switch protocol from HTTP to WS.

```
const socketStore = {}
io.on('connect', socket => {
  ...
  socketStore[customerId] = socket
})
```

On another end, every RabbitMQ message will have `customerId` in it as well which will be used to find appropriate `socket` object.

```
onNewMessage = message => {
  /**
   * Consumer parse the message and take customerId
   * and find a socket based on it
   */
  socketStore[customerId].emit(...)
}
```

The tricky part is that how to handle situation in which RabbitMQ consumer from whatever application instance will receive the message with customerId which cant be found in `socketStore`? So for the example, **instance number 1** received web socket connection with `customerId=10`, but **instance number 2** gets RabbitMQ message with that `customerId`. In that case **instance number 2** cant find associated socket.

Additionally, single customer can be logged in with different devices at same time(desktop, mobile, ipad, ...), as it seems to me `socketStore` (where `customerId` is a key) should have one or more socket object per device, such as:

```
const socketStore = {
  '10': [socket, socket, ..., socket]
}
```

Comment: You should store that map in redis or other fast in memory storage (using single instance that will "synchronize" every participant.

Comment: what if all of your instances will subscribe to all messages? makes the architecture simpler. If the customer Id is not found in the socket store, instance will just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

if scaling work loads, this keep one server to interact with customer, if he is online you can always find him. this structure shift the workloads to workers.

[image: scaling work loads]

[image: scaling work loads]

if scaling connections, if one server cannot hold all connections then you need a relay server to track user in a higher level
[image: scaling connections]

also you can use both

Comment: Hey I configured an rmq setup using node amqp in a websocket, but I'm having problems with receiving the messages that I publish to my exchanges. Can you please have a look at my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320526/aws-api-gateway-websocket-receives-messages-inconsistently, thanks!